# How to get SecurityToken in event reciever?

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, httpcontext

I have enabled FBA in my site. We are trying to override people picker with [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/05/26/fixing-people-picker-for-saml-claims-users-using-ldap/). We have override people picker method in farm level feature event receiver as suggested in method.

I am trying to call a service for getting users in event receiver. For that call I need to pass `SecurityToken`. I have stored user token in session on login page. Below is my code sample to get users:

```
 SecurityToken token = (SecurityToken)HttpContext.Current.Session["ServiceToken"];

                var service = _serviceGateway.GetServiceFactory<IGSRoleProvider>(token, _serviceGateway.RoleProviderEndpoint().Uri);
                var claims = string.Empty;

                //Building a claims string
                string key = companyid;
                string myValue = string.Empty;
                foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
                {
                    claims += claim + "\\n\\n";
                    if (claim.ClaimType == "http://mysite/claims/companyid")
                    {
                        key = claim.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                userSet = service.FindUsers(prefix, Convert.ToInt32(key));
                return userSet.Tables[0];
```

The issue I am facing is `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null in event receiver. So is there any other way we can get `SecurityToken` in event receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Farm level property bag as Session is not available in event receiver (or I should say claim provider event receiver). Below is code sample I use in my code:

```
SPFarm farmObject = SPFarm.Local;
if (farmObject.Properties != null && farmObject.Properties.Count > 0)
 {
   if (!farmObject.Properties.ContainsKey(loginusername))
    {
      farmObject.Properties[loginusername] = key;
      farmObject.Properties[loginusername + "login_token"] = ServiceToken;
    }
 }
```